# Ubuntu hangs on boot (dual boot)

Tags: boot, networking

Since I built a new PC (I moved over my SSDs), Ubuntu hangs on boot, hanging on the boot screen. Sometimes it seems boot, but it can't connect to the internet either through Wi-Fi or Ethernet. I have it dual booted with Windows 11.

Here are some boot messages:

```
usb 1-14: new low-speed USB device number using xhci_hcd
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-14: device not responding to setup address
usb 1-14: unable to enumerate USB device
Dependency failed for Swap Partition.
A start job is running for Network Time Synchronization
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please try showing the boot messages with ESC/↑/↓. If not possible, please enable verbose boot by editing `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: usb 1-14: new low-speed USB device number using xhci_hcd
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-14: device not responding to setup address
usb 1-14: unable to enumerate USB device
Dependency failed for Swap Partition.
A start job is running for Network Time Synchronization

Comment: This makes no sense? "unable to enumerate USB device Dependency failed for Swap Partition" Did you install swap on an USB and then removed USB, so system cannot find swap? Default install now has swapfile, not swap partition. But swap partition will be used if found or specified during install.